# programmatically button triggering?

Tags: c#, button

So I'm trying to make a button to so that when it is clicked, the button will turn transparrent, and a game in the background will begin. I'm new and don't know what i'm doing, but here is my code:

```
public Form1()
        {
            //Just ignore all this

            InitializeComponent();

            Label[] labelArray = { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5,
            label6, label7, label8, label9 };

            for (int i = 0; i < labelArray.Length; i++)
            {
                labelArray[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            }

            //Button details...
            Button buttonStart = new Button();

            buttonStart.Location = new Point(90, 150);
            buttonStart.Text = ("Click start to begin");
            buttonStart.Size = new Size(150, 50);

            //Adding the evnet handler
            buttonStart.Click += new EventHandler(buttonStart_Click);

            //Adding the button to the form
            this.Controls.Add(buttonStart);
            buttonStart.BringToFront();

            //Clicking it, in the hopes that what in (buttonStart_Click event
            //handler would do something)

            buttonStart.PerformClick();
        }

        //Eventhandler that says it cannot recoqnize
        //my "buttonStart", and I cannot seem to find any other way to do this

        private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttonStart.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.buttonStart.visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: This might work, yet the program still cannot recognize my "buttonStart" in the event handler for some reason

Comment: it should work ...

however, try this:   


(sender as button).Visible = false;

Comment: @Neebz You have to make `buttonStart` a property of your class to access it from other methods in that class. You can also use the designer to create that button and give it a name (it will do so in the `InitializeComponent` method), it will have the same effect.